# No CoreData Fetched Results in Nordic Countries

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, internationalization, nsfetchrequest

Frankly, I'm a little embarrassed to even ask this question for the perceived absurdity and without being able to personally reproduce it, but...

In my iOS 7 application, I've received many complaints from users that certain portions of the app "don't work." By "don't work," they mean that a `UITableView` being populated by a `NSFetchRequestDelegate`'s methods has zero rows. The only thing in common about the error reports are the specific `NSFetchRequests` that return zero objects and the physical location of the users. The users are all in Nordic countries (Norway, Sweeden, Finland, etc.). This could be a coincidence, or just that the Nordic are more vocal when there is a bug, but this bug makes me nervous.

I've tried setting my phone to use Nynorsk as the default language and using Nordic international units (which my app does happily support with `NSDateFormatter` and friends). The app works fine for me when I do this, but I am physically in the USA. I've even gone so far as to use a user account with my app whose server-side data was generated in Finland (all sorts of diacritics in strings that will be saved with CoreData), and it still works as expected.

I don't see anything abnormal with my instantiation of my `NSFetchedResultsController`, but for completeness, here is one that returns no results:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        return (_fetchedResultsController);

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kTTAEntityCheckinDetail inManagedObjectContext:MOC];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:kTTACheckinDetailBatchSize];

    NSSortDescriptor *checkinIDSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:kTTACheckinDetailAttributeCheckinID ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[checkinIDSort]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:MOC sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error] == NO)
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    return (_fetchedResultsController);
}
```

It's possible that `performFetch` is failing, but I do not have access to the user's logs. Perhaps I should detect the user's location and log this to a remote server?

---

**Solution**: CoreData failed to `save` the objects because a `date` field was `nil`. This field wasn't populated because the `locale` of a `NSDateFormatter` was not set. See the comments of @flexaddicted's accepted solution for details.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that snippet. I'd look at the code that's supposed to fill in the details of the cells, and at the code that creates and saves Core Data entries in the first place.

Comment: Try changing your locale and location to somewhere in Norway - this way You will simulate norway users. Maybe You are filtering data somewhere else, maybe there is wrong time zone used or wrong date format?

Comment: @thom_ek: I've done the locale changing, thought I didn't simulate a Norway GPS location. That's something I could try. The should be formatted correctly with a `NSDateFormatter` that I was able to confirm when switching locales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a shot in the dark.

First, what type of objects do you retrieve? Based on dates?

Then, Yes, I would log both locally and server-side. To log locally you could ask users in Nordic Countries to send a feedback (based on email) with Core Data store or just file logs (the logs will be inserted in the right points). The latter could be achieved by [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack).

An example of this can be found at [CocoaLumberjack](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/61-cocoa-lumberjack) and [Mailing logs](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/62-mailing-logs) by NSScreencast.

[TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) could be an alternative way but I guess you are in production.

Comment: The objects do have dates and the `UITableView` divides sections based on these, but they are formatted with a `NSDateFormatter` (`sectionIdentifier` formats this). Antenna looks like it might be a good way to figure this out.

Comment: ...and the `NSDateFormatter` it is. I was able to find an international user and used your TestFlight recommendation for remote logging. My hunch that the `performFetch` was failing was close. It was actually `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `save`, saying that my required field, `date`, was nil. It would seem the web service is returning different formats of dates in other countries, since my formatter works fine at least in the USA.

Comment: @greg Happy to ear this. Why your ws returns a different format in other countries? I would expect that it returns always the same format while the device formats dates based on current locale. e.g. the ws always returns a format like `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: I was waiting to log the date. Now that I have it, I have no idea. My `NSDateFormatter` has a format of `@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"` and `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4`. In Germany (country where I found help), `dateFromString:@"Thu, 09 Jan 2014 12:03:00 +0000"` returns `nil`, but here for me in the US, returns a valid `NSDate`. Maybe time to open a new SO question.

Comment: Actually when I change Settings > General > International > Region Format to something like "Belgium", the `NSDateFormatter` returns `nil`. "Germany" proper works, "Norway" works, "Danish (Denmark)" fails. This has to be the issue. I guess I need to learn more about formatting dates.

Comment: And to finish this up, `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];` to force the `NSDateFormatter` to parse the input date with a English US locale. Printing the date should use `[NSLocale currentLocale]` (the default?).

Comment: @greg take a look to http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/working-with-date-and-time. Hope it helps.